# CSS animated type is blocking view of Hero Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

UX designer here learning to code, please forgive my ignorance and sloppy code.

I have a hero image, and I have a CSS animated type that I have placed over it. The type blocks the view of the Hero Image though. Not sure why. I've gone through the CSS and stripped out any color or background info that might be interfering. By selectively commenting out classes, I think I have determined that the "link" class is the problem, but looking at it's CSS, I don't see why.

The Hero Image also has JS stuff applied to it but I don't think that is the root cause or interferes in any real way.

The JSFiddle for the project can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/thedonquixotic/8vv7t1as/

The relevant section of the HTML is this:

```
<!--Hero image with tilt effect-->

<div class="hero">
     <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="link link--kumya" href="About.html"><span data-letters="David French">David French</span></a>
            </div>

        <div class="hero__imgwrap">
            <img class="hero__img tilt-effect" data-tilt-options='{ "opacity" : 0.3, "extraImgs" : 3, "movement": { "perspective" : 1700, "translateX" : -7, "translateY" : -7, "rotateX" : -7, "rotateY" : -7 } }' src="images/welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome!" />
        </div>
</div>
<!--Hero image with tilt effect-->
```

Comment: check the position of your <img> and src

Comment: Okay so I've reversed the order of the grid_item and the Hero Image and now it overlays the background over the text. 

I also tried changing the position of the src within the img tag and that hasn't really effected anything. 

I think I've determined this isn't a link class issue, more has to do with the order I'm putting things on the page?

Comment: Okay so I put the grid_item inside of the hero_imgwrap div. I thought I'd tried that before but for some reason it worked this time.

**EDIT:** Oh wait, nope. This doesn't work. It only worked because I disabled the tilteffect class on the background...

Comment: Okay so traced back the tilt-effect class to the tiltfx.js file and found this function:

`function init() {
  // search for imgs with the class "tilt-effect"
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img.tilt-effect')).forEach(function(img) {
   new TiltFx(img, JSON.parse(img.getAttribute('data-tilt-options')));
  });
 }`